# MVC Entity framework and Owin Oauth merge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oauth-2.0, owin

In my MVC app I am working with the EntityFramwork, and I Would like to use the Owin Oauth of MVC.
Is there a possibility that I can connect the Owin with my custom Db Users.
How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it? What code do you already have? Where have you stopped?

Comment: I don't know where to start or even if its possible. Thats why this question.

Comment: At least describe which kind of OAuth you want to use. Is it a custom OAUth server or you would like to use it with Facebook or Twitter. Do you have already any OWIN middleware in your app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement oauth2 server in ASP.NET MVC 5 and WEB API 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755573/how-to-implement-oauth2-server-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)