# Cortana skill enable ASP.Net Identity Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, cortana-skills-kit

I have created a MVC custom web application with ASP.Net Identity provider and it worked fine. Now I want to enable that single sign on authentication in Cortana skill using the connected account (similar to Expedia Skill). Do you have any suggestions?

Here are the steps that I followed for enabling the custom Authenticaiton

[ASP.Net Identity provider](http://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

I have Tried the steps given here, but somehow the token is not getting back to Cortana skill. Is there any way to troubleshoot the cortana authentication flow.

[Cortana External Auth](https://help.knowledge.store/system_concepts/authentication/index.html#calling-back-to-the-user-session)

Comment: Have you implemented an Oauth2 server? ASP.Net identity might not be enough. See how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755573/how-to-implement-oauth2-server-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: Yes. I saw this as well. My  provider is Asp.net mvc based I dont want angular for login page. I thought of trying out the basic before go deeper. Also, I couldn't send my Oauth2 token back to Cortana. I tried HttpResponce and Redirect as well. but no success..