# Adding OAuth2 Authentication to the existing ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

We have an `ASP.NET MVC 5` app and need to authenticate users via an organization by using the following info:

Redirect Uri, Client Id, Secret Key, token_uri, resource_uri.

There are several tutorials explaining this e.g. [How to implement oauth2 server in ASP.NET MVC 5 and WEB API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755573/how-to-implement-oauth2-server-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and [Create an ASP.NET MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) but most of them use `Azure` or `Web API`, but I do not want to use `API` or `Azure`. So, how can I implement this `OAuth2 Authentication`?

**Update:**

Here is my code using @WiktorZychla's tutorial. But id does not seem to work :(

***web.config:***

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".DemoAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" 
          slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

***View:***

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Authorize", "Account")';
    return false;" />Login</button>
```

***Controller:***

```
public readonly GoogleClient gClient = new GoogleClient
{
    AuthorizationTracker = new MyAuthorizationTracker(),
    ClientIdentifier = "x...", //client id
    ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter("x...") //secret
};

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
    IAuthorizationState authorization = gClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

    // Is this a response from the Identity Provider
    if (authorization == null)
    {
        // no

        // Google will redirect back here
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:53105/Account/Login");

        // Kick off authorization request with OAuth2 scopes
        gClient.RequestUserAuthorization(returnTo: uri,
            scope: new[] { GoogleClient.OpenId, 
                GoogleClient.ProfileScope, GoogleClient.EmailScope });
    }
    else
    {
        // yes

        var request = WebRequest.Create(GoogleClient.ProfileEndpoint);

        // add an OAuth2 authorization header
        // if you get 403 here, turn ON Google+ API on your app settings page
        request.Headers.Add(
             HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,
             string.Format("Bearer {0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken)));

        // Go to the profile API
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var profile = GoogleProfileAPI.Deserialize(responseStream);
                if (profile != null &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.email))
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(profile.email, false);
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I wrote a [tutorial](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simple-oauth2-federated-authentication.html) years ago, it's still ok to do Oauth2 this way in a classic mvc5 app.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks Wiktor, I also have seen some outdated tutorials. But if there is not any difference or update, I can use them. Is it good idea to use them or should I have a look at an updated version written for the last 1-2- years?

Comment: @WiktorZychla On the other hand, your code seems to be written for ASP.NET and I am not sure if it works for ASP.NET MVC. Any idea?

Comment: @DaImTo I think you directly voted down without reading the question title. I am looking for an implementation to the **existing** ASP.NET MVC project that may be a default MVC project given on the beginner tutorials. So, there is no need to post all of the unnecessary code here, right?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Any helps please?

Comment: @DaImTo What about this [How to implement custom authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584506/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5)???

Comment: this will work with MVC as well. Just think in terms of controllers/actions rather than pages and the code is the same. You redirect anonymous requests to a controller/action that does authentication where you copy-paste the code I show. We use this in multiple MVC apps.

Comment: @WiktorZychla If you would not mind, could you pls post the code on that page by modifying for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @DaImTo What about my last update?

Comment: I need to use custom API instead of Google API. How can I define a custom API in the code above? Maybe I need another definition instead of **GoogleClient**.

Comment: I think I need to use OWIN and make some changes i.e. adding Startup.Auth.cs file. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a custom definition of the OAuth2 client.

Comment: Yes, but how??? I encountered **'IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication' and no accessible extension method 'UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'IAppBuilder' could be found** error when using **app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication** :(